# Deploying Model in Google Cloud: Create Version failed. Model validation failed: SavedModel must contain exactly one metagraph with tag: serve

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to deploy in Google Cloud a model trained locally. I trained the model and save the graph .pb and also quantise the model. However, now that I'm trying to deploy it, I receive the following error:

```
Create Version failed. Model validation failed: SavedModel 
must contain exactly one metagraph with tag: serve
```

Does anyone know how to add the tag to the model?

Comment: You may find this link helpful:

https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you export your model (code snippets would be most helpful)? When you export models you're allowed to save more than one graph, but the service is expecting only one and it must be called "serve".

Comment: @rhaertel80 I was able to solve it. I already post the answer. Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    input_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                            shape=(None, spec.crop_size, spec.crop_size, spec.channels),
                            name='input')
    y_ = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, 2])

    # Create builder
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

    tensor_info_x = utils.build_tensor_info(input_node)
    tensor_info_y = utils.build_tensor_info(y_)


    prediction_signature = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs={'input': tensor_info_x},
            outputs={'output': tensor_info_y},
            method_name=signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME)

    legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        signature_def_map={
            'predict_images':
            prediction_signature
        },
        legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)

    # Save the SavedModel to disk.
    builder.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer of Zapata still left somethings to the imagination. Here my code:

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        input_x = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("0:0")  # input
        outputs1 = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("add_10:0")
        output_tf_pb = sess.run(
            [outputs1], feed_dict={input_x: np.random.randn(1, 3, 64, 64)}
        )
        # output_tf_pb = sess.run([outputs1, outputs2], feed_dict= 
    {input_x:np.random.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)})
        print("output_tf_pb = {}".format(output_tf_pb))

    # os.removedirs("output2")
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("output2")
    prediction_signature = 
    tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
        inputs={"images": tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(input_x)},
        outputs={"scores": tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(outputs1)},
        method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME,
    )
    tensor_info_x = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(input_x)
    tensor_info_y = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(outputs1)

    classification_signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
        inputs={tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS: tensor_info_x},
        outputs={
            tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES: tensor_info_y
        },
        method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME,
    )

    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        sess,
        [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        signature_def_map={
            "predict_images": prediction_signature,
            tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: classification_signature,
        },
        main_op=tf.tables_initializer(),
    )
    builder.save()
```

The full file can be found at:

https://gist.github.com/takotab/ccd131fb06d4cdd2b786b3ef83c62ade